# Image manipulation in asp.net/c# without System.Drawing/GDI+

Tags: asp.net, system.drawing

Is there any alternative image manipulation library for .net?  I would prefer something that is managed and open source.

I ask this because of two reasons:

1. I have encountered hard to debug GDI+ errors with System.Drawing in the past
2. I have read that using System.Drawing in asp.net web applications is not 100% supported.

Thanks!

edit: clarification, I know that System.Drawing can work asp.net web apps - I have used it in the past.  I really just wonder if there are any managed image manipulation libraries for .net :)

Comment: Managed bitmap operations are inherently slow. Pretty much anything usable will be a managed wrapper, because assembly-level optimizations (SSE) are needed to get fast jpeg encoding and decoding. I suggest you take a look at [the ImageResizing.Net library](http://imageresizing.net). It does 99% of what most people need, and it handles all of GDI's bugs and quirks. It also is know to properly run websites with millions of images and millions of visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any fully-managed 2D drawing libraries that are either free or open-source  (there appears to be a few commercially available, but OSS is the way to go). However, you might look into [the Mono bindings to Cairo](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?tlink=0@N:Cairo).

Cairo is a platform independent 2D drawing API. You can find more information about it at [the Cairo homepage](http://cairographics.org). The [Cairo Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_(graphics)) also has some good info.

Cairo is also used fairly widely in the Open Source world, which to me says something about its robustness. Mozilla, Webkit, and Mono all use it, among others. Ironically, Mono actually uses it to back their System.Drawing implementation... go figure.

There might also be a way to use Mono's System.Drawing implementation as a drop-in replacement for the Microsoft implementation, though I'm not sure how or if that would even work. I would probably start by replacing the System.Drawing.dll reference with Mono's version, and then try to deal with any errors.

Comment: Mono's System.Drawing is kind of incomplete... DrawImage, for one, doesn't implement many of the overloads... I'm trying to find a workaround so I can support Mono in the http://imageresizing.net library.

Comment: The latest version of Mono supports DrawImage, so many operations now work.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into [the WPF Imaging libraries shipped with .NET 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.aspx). They're optimized and robust (used to run Aero, so you know they're efficient). They don't depend on the WPF dispatcher, are easily extensible, and officially supported. What more could you want?

Comment: Pretty sure that Aero doesn't run on WPF, seeing as you don't need to have .NET installed to get Aero working in Windows.

Comment: Apparently WPF has issues of it's own through asp.net.  See the "update" and comments sections from Bertrand Le Roy -- http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/01/21/server-side-resizing-with-wpf-now-with-jpg.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotal evidence #1:  I have used GDI+ for on-the-fly image creation within ASP.NET with no problems.  I'm not sure what the problems would even be.

Comment: The System.Drawing namespace is not supported, MS says so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx 
So the chance of encountering serious problems is definately there..

Answer (score 0):

With respect to (1), most of the hard to debug errors are due to not closing open handles (Dispose() in managed-land).  I'm curious where you heard (2).

Comment: Microsoft has a warning in the .NET docs for (2): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx