# Can System.Drawing be used in an Azure web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

I have a web site that I'm planning to move from an old-school web hosting company to Microsoft Azure.  It's an ASP.NET application that uses System.Drawing to render some graphics.  I've read some things about GDI not being supported on Azure web sites.  Does this mean that System.Drawing won't work, or is it only an issue when calling directly into gdi32.dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accroding to the wiki [page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) & the description for [`System.Drawing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), it seems that `System.Drawing` is not supported on Azure WebApps, even using some features with not GDI required.

If you want to re-implement the feature fro rendering some graphics without `System.Drawing` or `GDI`, the SO thread [Image manipulation in asp.net/c# without System.Drawing/GDI+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299/image-manipulation-in-asp-net-c-without-system-drawing-gdi) may be helpful for you.

However, I suggest that the better way is using some visual libraries in JS like `D3.js` or `ECharts` to render these graphics you want at the frontend of browser.

Comment: Thank you very much.  So, am I reading this correctly to infer that I can use Cairo to render my images with .NET Core on Azure?

Comment: @golubdr If using Cairo with .NET Core binding and no GDI required, yes, you can render your images on Azure